# Creating a JSON file(MongoDb Collection) of User Info for a Node.js application that uses Bcrypt and passport for login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I'll try and word this question as short and clear as possible. I have a node.js project that connects to a non local instance of MongoDB using mongoose. I have written code for a user to login using passport module. I create a JSON file as a users collection. When I go to sign in I get this error

```
throw "Not a valid BCrypt hash."
```

So If I wanted to just create a JSON file of Users to work with this how would I go about it? My end goal is to convert RDBMS to MongoDB. Just starting with the users table. I understand that if I was registering new users I could just make a function that would hash their password like

```
newUser.password= createHash(password)

    var createHash = function(password){
            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
        }
```

or something along those lines. Summary: How do I make a JSON file of user info for MongoDB that'll work with bcrypt hash and passport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bc = require('bcrypt-nodejs')

fs.readFile('users.txt',function(err,data){
   var x = [];
   if(err) throw err;
   var buf = new Buffer(data);
   x = buf.toString();
   x = JSON.parse(x);
   //console.log(x);
   for(var a in x){
    x[a].password=createHash(x[a].password);
   }
   x = JSON.stringify(x);
   fs.writeFile('users.txt',x,callback()); //or just push directly to db?
});

var createHash = function(password){
            return bc.hashSync(password, bc.genSaltSync(10), null);
        }

function callback(){
    console.log('finished');
}
```

Just read in my User Info , Bcrypted the passwords and made a new file. Put it in Mongo. Hopefully this helps someone else. If anyone has a better solution for me I'd appreciate it.